# GenerateJavaTask does not show up in netflix dgs package

Tags: kotlin, gradle, graphql

What am I missing in `build.gradle.kts file`?

```
import com.netflix.graphql.dgs.codegen.gradle.GenerateJavaTask
plugins {id("com.netflix.dgs.codegen") version "5.4.0"}
dependencies {implementation("com.netflix.graphql.dgs.codegen:graphql-dgs-codegen-gradle:5.4.0")}
```

and getting error when calling `GenerateJavaTask`

```
tasks.withType<com.netflix.graphql.dgs.codegen.gradle.GenerateJavaTask> {
    generateClient = true
    packageName = "com.house.api.generated"
}
```

error (which are pointing to above lines):

```
Unresolved reference: GenerateJavaTask
Unresolved reference: GenerateJavaTask
Type mismatch: inferred type is () -> Unit but Class<TypeVariable(S)!> was expected
Unresolved reference: generateClient
Unresolved reference: packageName
```

Comment: Can you post the complete stacktrace? Run with —stacktrace

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar please check. before first line its successful type generations. added stacktrace.

Comment: You need to also post the schema. The issue is obviously with the codegen plugin having issue with your schema.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar without adding code build is successful and server runs. when adding code gen it does not read `GenerateJavaTask` from the lib. there should be some problem with syntax or something I miss. the only class shows in `com.netflix.graphql.dgs.codegen.gradle.` is `CodegenPluginExtension`

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar you are right, the problem was with schema. however `codegen` is generating code in build directory. i still need to define a task as explained but it is not reading `GenerateJavaTask`